# How Do I filter out names of folders in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, filter, directory

I have the code searching through the directory and picks out all the folders, but I only want it to pick out ones that Start with Data.    How would I do that?

Below is the code I have that goes through the Directory:

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath).Where(Data => !Data.EndsWith(".")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to use LINQ; [`GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx) supports search patterns, and will probably be significantly faster since the filtering may be done by the filesystem, *before* enumerating the results in .NET.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath, "Data*");
```

Note that `*` is a wildcard which matches zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

If "starts with data" you just mean the folder name begins with "Data", this will work

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath)
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("Data") && !s.EndsWith(".")).ToArray();
```